# How do I check if string starts with any letter, as in a-z or A-Z?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Here is the context

```
if (self.display.text hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = ", ANYLETTER])
```

Thanks Matt, I changed it a bit so it still checked for the rest of the formatting I had, now it works as expected. :)

```
if ([self.display.text rangeOfString:@" = "].location == 1 && [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self.display.text characterAtIndex:0]])
```

EDITED: This just checks if the first character is a letter

```
char character = [self.display.text characterAtIndex:0];
if ([[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character] || [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character])
{
    //String Starts With a Letter
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ([[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[self.display.text characterAtIndex:0]])
{
    // Starts with letter.
}
```

Comment: Careful! This character set includes two characters that, literally speaking, aren't letters: `\`` and `^`. [http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSCharacterSet](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSCharacterSet)

Comment: You could simply check if the character is a lowercase letter or an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
unichar ch = [[[self display] text] characterAtIndex:0];
BOOL startsWithLetter = (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
```

You could also use a regex library/method to check, but the above is pretty simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `- (NSRange)rangeOfCharacterFromSet:(NSCharacterSet *)aSet` of `NSString` and pass `[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]` and check if the location of the range is 0.